# Удаление сообщение через некоторое время в Telegram

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Как в телеграме реализовать удаление сообщение через N минут после отправки его ботом?

Использую библиотеку [TelegramBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots)

Пример: бот отправил сообщение "привет". Юзер написал уже сообщений 100 после отправки ботом "привет". Спустя 58 минут бот удалил сообщение "привет".

Answer (score 2):

Предложу такой вариант.

Возьмем как допущение:

1. Время, через которое надо удалять отправленные ботом сообщения, постоянно.
2. Время сервера с запущенным ботом синхронизировано и не отличается от времени серверов Telegram.

Создаем однонаправленную очередь,

```java
Queue<Message> eraseQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

в которую будем помещать отправленные ботом сообщения

```java
Message sentMessage = bot.execute(message);
bot.eraseQueue.add(sentMessage);
```

Постоянно, в отдельном потоке, проверяем наличие сообщений в очереди "eraseQueue".
При наличии сообщения читаем дату и время отправки

```java
Long sentDate = message.getDate().longValue();
```

Дата и время будут с сервера Telegram-а.
Сверяем с текущей датой-временем и если разница во времени больше заданного (через которое надо удалить сообщение), то формируем и отправляем "DeleteMessage" беря необходимые данные из "sentMessage".
Если время меньше, вычисляем разницу (через сколько нужно удалить сообщение) и на это время останавливаем выполнение текущего потока.
После формируем и отправляем "DeleteMessage".
И снова проверяем наличие сообщений в очереди.

Отдельный поток запускаем в методе main.

Пример:

```java
public class Bot {
//    ...
    Queue<Message> eraseQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
//    ...
}


public class MessageSender implements Runnable {
    private Bot bot;

    public MessageSender(Bot bot) {
        this.bot = bot;
    }

//    ...

                    Message sentMessage = bot.execute(message);
                    bot.eraseQueue.add(sentMessage);

//    ...
}


public class MessageEraser implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessageEraser.class);
    private final long ERASER_TIME = 58;  //time in minutes
    private Bot bot;

    public MessageEraser(Bot bot) {
        this.bot = bot;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.info("[STARTED] MsgEraser. Bot class: " + bot);
        try {
            //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
            while (true) {
                for (Message message = bot.eraseQueue.poll(); message != null; message = bot.eraseQueue.poll()) {
                    log.debug("Msg to erase " + message);
                    Long sentDate = message.getDate().longValue();
                    Instant instantMsgSentTime = java.time.Instant.ofEpochSecond(sentDate);
                    Instant instantCurrentTime = Clock.systemUTC().instant();
                    long difference = ERASER_TIME * 60 * 1_000 - instantMsgSentTime.until(instantCurrentTime, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
                    if (difference > 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(difference);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            log.error("Take interrupt while operate msg queue", e);
                        }
                    }
                    erase(message);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

    private void erase(Message message) {
        Long chatId = message.getChatId();
        Integer messageId = message.getMessageId();
        DeleteMessage deleteMessage = new DeleteMessage()
                .setChatId(chatId)
                .setMessageId(messageId);
        bot.sendQueue.add(deleteMessage);
    }
}


public class App {
//    ...  
    private static final int PRIORITY_FOR_ERASER = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        Bot myBot;
        myBot = new Bot(Config.get().getBotName(), Config.get().getBotToken());
        myBot.botConnect();

//    ...  

        MessageEraser messageEraser = new MessageEraser(myBot);
        Thread eraser = new Thread(messageEraser);
        eraser.setDaemon(true);
        eraser.setName("MsgEraser");
        eraser.setPriority(PRIORITY_FOR_ERASER);
        eraser.start();
    }
}
```